# Pentaho Error: Duplicate entry for key 'PRIMARY'

Tags: pentaho-spoon

The error that Pentaho gives is when trying to insert new records of the steep Merge Rows (diff): 
Error updating batch codigo_postal.0 - Duplicate entry '01002' for key 'PRIMARY'.

The transformation:
[image: transformation]

Table input final: is a select from table A:
[image]

Table input aux: is a select from table B:
[image]

Merge Rows (diff) (preview): (row 01002 is **identical**)
[image: merge-rows-diff]

Switch / Case: (only rows new for codigo_postal steep)
[image: switch-case]

In steep Switch / Case (previer): the row '01002' is not in the result (only new rows) but the error is Error updating batch codigo_postal.0 - Duplicate entry '**01002**' for key 'PRIMARY'.

Does anyone know what may be happening?.

Thank you.

Comment: Are both streams sorted ? Your query is using a sort of 'order by' clause ? This is very important, if they aren't, you can use a Sort Rows step after each table input. Also make sure both columns are of the same type, different types will yield unwanted results.

Comment: Yes, i have order by and similar type, I have edited the question adding this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

ok, changing the data type to UNSIGNED worked correctly for me:

CAST(cp.id_codigo_postal AS UNSIGNED)

Thank you.